# How do I shrink the partition of an img file made from dd?

Tags: linux, partitioning, dd, gparted, parted

I've copied the USB drive to an `.img` file using `dd`:

```
dd if=/dev/sdc of=myimage.img
```

I want to reduce the size of the partition in the image. I've tried several methods and always end up with a loopback-mounted image whose partition is still the full size of the USB.

- How do I modify `myimage.img` to have a smaller partition once loopback-mounted?
- Do I need to copy zeros into the empty part of the partition before doing so?
- Do I need to defragment so that when I reduce the image size, I'm deleting empty bytes? (From what I've read, Linux spreads out into the whole partition so I have no expectation that all of the data at the end of the image are zero bytes. Even writing all zeros will just consume the empty bytes wherever they lie.)

NOTE: I'm not trying to save disk space, so zipping doesn't help me.

**BACKGROUND**

I have Linux installed on a USB drive using `ext4`. I intend to duplicate the install for multiple devices. I've done so successfully but would like to create on the same USB drive a read-only partition with the system and a small partition that allows persistent storage. Rather than break my USB, I'm trying to modify a copy of the USB. I hope we don't get distracted by this background.

In short, I've done the following:

```
# Create mount point in current directory
sudo mkdir mnt
# Loopback mount the image
fdisk -l myimage.img
sudo mount -o offset=<partion_block_start * block_size> myimage.img mnt
# Copy all zeros to remaining space of the image
cd mnt
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=filler conv=fsync bs=1M
rm filler
cd ..
```

First, I tried to use `parted` as described in [this SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/693186/201206) and `qemu-img` as described in [this other SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/1328570/201206).

```
sudo umount mnt
parted myimage.img
# At parted command prompt
(parted) resizepart 1
# Entered my end <target size>. Note that parted uses zero-based 
# indexing. This could be your final image size. In my case, the way the
# Linux installer worked, the partition started at 1M.
(parted) print
# I see that the partition is now sized as I expect
(parted) exit
# Just another sanity check
sudo parted -m esp3_007.img unit B print
# I see that the partition is now sized as I expect
```

When I try to mount the image again, it works fine but `df` still shows the partition as the same size. So then I tried

```
qemu-img resize myimage.img <target_size>
```

And now, when I try to mount the image, I get the "mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock..." error message.

Then I tried using `gparted` as described in [this off-site post](https://softwarebakery.com//shrinking-images-on-linux). The GUI showed a full partition unless I ran `parted` in the first place. Even then, the GUI wouldn't let me resize the partition.

For trying to force the partition size to be smaller, and starting with a fresh copy of `myimage.img` I tried `fdisk` described in [this AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/119458/524868)

```
sudo fdisk myimage.img
Command (m for help): d
Command (m for help): n
Command action
   e   extended
   p   primary partition (1-4)
p
Partition number (1-4, default 1): 1
# defaults on the rest seemed to be correct in my case.
```

When I mounted the partition, it still showed as the same size.

Comment: *NOTE: I'm not trying to save disk space* - then why bother? Just copying files works A-OK for linux, then add a bootloader

Comment: As I stated, I need to change the partition size to add another partition without reinstalling Linux.

Comment: You don't have to reinstall, just copy the files + grub/etc

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### On loop images

First of all, forget `offset=`, use `losetup --partscan` and just mount the partition via `/dev/loop0p1`.

```
# losetup --partscan /dev/loop0 myimage.img
# lsblk
# mount /dev/loop0p1 /mnt
```

To efficiently clear empty space within a partition, run `fstrim` on the loop-mounted filesystem, just like you would on an SSD. (This will actually make the image file sparse.)

```
# fstrim -v /mnt
```

#### On resizing partitions

But for now, you don't need to clear empty space or do anything like that. Whether the about-to-be-truncated area is filled with zeros or with chunks of old data is completely irrelevant.

Instead, you need to do exactly the same as you would do with ext4 on a real disk – you need to shrink each layer from the inside out. You cannot skip steps just because it's an image.

To shrink a partition that contains a filesystem, you must first tell the **filesystem** to shrink itself. For ext2/3/4 this is done using `resize2fs`. This will relocate data that might be living in the area you're about to chop off, and will store the new boundaries as part of the filesystem's metadata. (I suppose that's what you meant by "defragmenting" it.)

Only once the filesystem has been shrunk you can also shrink the partition containing it. This can be done via parted or fdisk by just changing the partition's end address.

Side note: You *should* be able to use GParted to resize the filesystem and the partition in one step – if it supports with working on loop devices, that is. It might depend on GParted's version. (However, the CLI *parted* cannot shrink filesystems, it just truncates the partition.)

Finally, once both the filesystem and the partition have been resized, you can truncate the whole image containing them. To do that, first detach the loop device and use `truncate --size=...` on your image file.

(To do it safely without having to do careful calculations, I would shrink the filesystem slightly more than needed to create some 'buffer' space; e.g. if I wanted a 4 GB image, I'd shrink the filesystem to 3 GB, the partition to 3.5 GB, and then truncate the image to 4 GB. Then grow everything in the opposite order to fill the 'buffer' space.)

Comment: BTW, `gparted` wasn't working for similar reasons the other commands weren't working: `gparted` doesn't work directly on image files. Looping back, using `losetup` as described in this answer and then running `gparted` on the `/dev/loopx` allows for resizing.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness’s sake, I add my semi-automatic script for resizing image based on these two answers [[1](https://superuser.com/questions/1373289/how-do-i-shrink-the-partition-of-an-img-file-made-from-dd/1373296#1373296)], [[2](https://serverfault.com/questions/796758/shrink-partition-to-exactly-fit-the-underlying-filesystem-size/796767#796767)]. This script resizes partitions so that image could be written to the smaller devices.

This script assumes that disk has only one `ext` partition.

- create image from `/dev/disk`

  ```bash
  sudo dd if=/dev/disk of=/tmp/disk_image.img status=progress bs=16M oflag=sync
  sudo chown $USER disk_image.img
  ```
- resize file system to minimum and calculate its size

  ```bash
  sudo losetup --partscan /dev/loop0 disk_image.img
  sudo e2fsck -f /dev/loop0p1
  sudo resize2fs /dev/loop0p1 -M
  block_count=$(sudo tune2fs -l /dev/loop0p1 | grep 'Block count' | sed 's/[^0-9]//g')
  block_size=$(sudo tune2fs -l /dev/loop0p1 | grep 'Block size' | sed 's/[^0-9]//g')
  fs_size=$((block_count * block_size))
  sudo losetup --detach /dev/loop0
  ```
- resize partition to fit underlying file system

  ```bash
  sudo losetup --partscan /dev/loop0 disk_image.img
  start=$(sudo parted /dev/loop0 unit B print --json | jq -r '.disk.partitions[0].start[0:-1]')
  end=$((start + fs_size))
  sudo parted /dev/loop0 resizepart 1 ${end}B
  blocks=$(sudo parted /dev/loop0 unit s print --json | jq -r '.disk.partitions[0].end[0:-1]')
  block_size=$(sudo parted /dev/loop0 unit s print --json | jq -r '.disk["physical-sector-size"]')
  end=$((blocks * block_size))
  sudo losetup --detach /dev/loop0
  truncate -s $end disk_image.img
  ```
- make sparse files

  ```bash
  sudo losetup --partscan /dev/loop0 disk_image.img
  mkdir /tmp/disk_image
  sudo mount /dev/loop0p1 /tmp/disk_image
  sudo fstrim -v /tmp/disk_image
  sudo umount /tmp/disk_image
  sudo losetup --detach /dev/loop0
  ```

Comment: For me the best answer. But the `--json` option is not recognized by parted

Comment: Edit: it is working in the last version at time of writing this (3.6). I had to compile it by myself in Debian 10